# How to deserialize an expanding JSON file?

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

How to deserialize that JSON file to an C# object?

```
{
   "arch": {
      "name": "Arch Linux",
      "source": "image"
   },
   "ubuntu": {
     "name": "Ubuntu",
     "source": "image"
   }
}
```

Comment: Define "expanding" please. That looks like a completely ordinary json file, and searching for a way to deserialize takes as much effort as typing your title into Google

Comment: What had you tries so far and where did you fail ... there is already bazzilion questions about json deserialization

Comment: Ok, I will try to explain this as well as I can. This is a configuration file to the c# app. User should be able to add more entries to that file. I want to convert that into a some kind of dictonary with an index. I made a simple dictonary myself for testing purposes. However now I want to use that JSON file instead of that dictonary.

Comment: If you don't want to use `Newtonsoft.Json`, and you want to use `System.Text.Json`, then specify it concretely in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
//using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

you can do

```
    string json = @"{
           'arch': {
              'name': 'Arch Linux',
              'source': 'image'
           },
           'ubuntu': {
             'name': 'Ubuntu',
             'source': 'image'
           }
        }";

    Dictionary<string, Settings> config =
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Settings>>(json);
```

Where `Settings` class like this:

```
public class Settings
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
}
```

You need to install **Newtonsoft.Json** NuGet package. How, see this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio

Comment: Do you know how to achieve that using `JsonSerializer.Deserialize`?

Comment: @Jakub Wrobel It is much complicated, you need to define custom DictionaryConvertor and use it as an option which is a big effort, the solution above is simple and effective. Remember KISS (Keep It Short and Simple)

Answer (score 1):

There may be an error in the @UsemeAlehosaini response. Most likely your solution won't work because the Settings class doesn't match the JSON structure you are trying to deserialize.

```
public class Arch
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
}

public class Ubuntu
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    public Arch Arch { get; set; }
    public Ubuntu Ubuntu { get; set; }
}
```

@JakubWrobel could you please try putting these classes instead of Settings?